# Statically center div on screen (no JS)

Tags: html, css

What I already have:

```css
    .modal-m1
    {
     background-image: url(../images/bg-greyout.png);
     background-repeat: repeat;
     display: table;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     position: fixed;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     z-index: 1;
    }
    .modal-m1 .modal-m2
    {
     display: table-cell;
     vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .dialogbox
    {
     margin: 0 auto;
     background-color: #F6F6F6;
     -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
        -moz-border-radius: 20px;
        border-radius: 20px;
     -webkit-box-shadow: #666 3px 3px 5px;
     -moz-box-shadow: #666 3px 3px 5px;
        box-shadow: #666 3px 3px 20px;
        padding: 20px;
    }
    .mydialogbox
    {
        width: 400px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="modal-m1">
        <div class="modal-m2">
            <div class="dialogbox mydialogbox">
            ... CONTENT IS HERE ......
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Everything is okay on that stage. You may test it on snippet.

Now I want to put several dialog boxes to different pages. I'm trying to reuse the code and for that reason I'm trying to extract `modal-m1`, `modal-m2` and `dialogbox` to ASP.NET user control. `mydialogbox` must become a nested `div` inside of `dialogbox`. But `dialogbox` ignores `width: 400px` in this case. Is there any workaround?

In other words, I want my markup to be:

```
<div class="modal-m1">
    <div class="modal-m2">
        <div class="dialogbox">
            <div class="mydialogbox">
            ... CONTENT IS HERE ......
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the issue correctly, but if you just need to center a div without all that hassle, try this article: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/

Comment: I do not know height (it is based on content) and I want to declare width for `<div class="mydialogbox">...  CONTENT HERE ......</div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I undestood..
your html can be like this:

```
   <div class="modal-m1">
        <div class="modal-m2">
            <div class="dialogbox ">
                <div class="mydialogbox">
                    <div>CONTENT IS HERE ......</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and you want put width only for .mydialogbox

```
.modal-m1 .modal-m2
{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align:center; /*add*/
}
.dialogbox
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #F6F6F6;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: #666 3px 3px 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: #666 3px 3px 5px;
    box-shadow: #666 3px 3px 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    display:inline-block; /*change*/
}
.mydialogbox
{
    width: 400px;
    text-align:left
}
```

is this?

Comment: Wow... this one works (at least on IE 11)! Is it possible to run it on IE 7 (do not care about shadows, centering etc.)?

Comment: Okay, I have found myself... `zoom: 1; *display: inline` instead of `display:inline-block` does the trick.